# How to disallow var keyword under .net 2.0 target?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I created new project in Visual Studio with target framework 2.0. But even if I left somewhere `var` keyword Visual Studio successfully compiles project. Is this the correct behavior as `var` is 3.0 feature? Is there any settings to prevent code with `var` to be compiled?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`var` is a feature of *C#* 3.0, but it doesn't require any *framework* features. In other words, it's absolutely fine to use within a project targeting .NET 2.0. The same is true of many other features - anonymous types, automatic properties, lambda expressions etc.

See my [versions article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Versions.aspx) for more information. (I need to update it for C# 4 at some point...)

If you *want* to restrict yourself to C# 2.0, you can specify the language version by clicking on "Advanced" in the Build tab of the project properties, IIRC. (It's definitely there somewhere, but I'd rather have a cup of coffee than check for the exact location right now.)

Comment: +1. /langversion (C# Compiler Options) (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4ckecs0.aspx)

Comment: Thanks both Jon and desco! This is exactly what I want - to restrict language features to C# 2.0.

Answer (score 3):

`var` is purely a compile-time feature, once the assembly is compiled, the compiler inserts the *actual* type and the fact that you had used `var` is "lost".

So a project that's targetting version 2.0 of the framework can still make use of the `var` feature, because it doesn't actually affect the outputted assembly in any way.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your project will always be compiled with Visual Studio 2008 or newer, you're safe to use C# 3.0 features. The .NET 2.0 target only restricts what libraries you can use, not what language features.

Comment: The purpose why I need to restrict my code to 2.0 that it is supposed to be compiled under pure .NET Framework 2.0 afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

Either do full text replace of var by 1var1 and manually replace them or use pre 3.0 versions of compiler.